# Python XVFB error in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

For virtual Framebuffer (headless testing) I'm using `Xvfb` with `PyVirtualDisplay` and it's working fine in Ubuntu but showing error in Windows7. here is part of code where problem is occurring.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=1, size=(300, 400))
display.start()
```

but when I run same command in Windows, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pynt-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pynt==0.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'pynt')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynt\_pynt.py", line 295, in main
    build(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynt\_pynt.py", line 48, in build
    module = imp.load_source(path.splitext(path.basename(args.file))[0], args.fi
le)
  File "build.py", line 7, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=1, size=(300,400))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 33, in
__init__
    self._obj = self.display_class(
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 50, in
display_class
    cls.check_installed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\xvfb.py", line 34, in che
ck_installed
    ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\easyprocess\__init__.py", line 209, in che
ck_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Program install error!
```

I think my program is not able to find xvfb program/library ? 
I installed xvfbwrapper (https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper) but problem still remain same. again I think xvfbwrapper is different from xvfb?

Any alternative for Windows platform which can do headless testing (virtual framebuffer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an error because command [`Xvfb`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) was not found. Xvfb is X virtual framebuffer which is not a part of Microsoft Windows 7.

Comment: You can't install Xvfb on Windows. Look this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/480261/124457)