# ImportError: No module named 'display'

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x

I am using `Selenium` for webscraping

I want to hide the browser that open while Selinium makes request. I have just installed `PyVirtualDisplay-0.1.5`. I am running Windows 8.1

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

I am getting this error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'display'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python XVFB error in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063833/python-xvfb-error-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyvirtualdisplay` requires `Xvfb` to work.  It is not available for Windows, because there is no X server.

Comment: Ok I get it... actually I will then run my code on Amazon Cloud machines ... will I be able to turn off browser there?

Comment: @Mani, yes, if you use Linux